# Sot convergence of a net

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

The following are exercises of Conway's operator theory: [image][image]

I proved both exercises, but I confused about this point that in exercise 8, $T_i\to 0$ (sot), so based on exercise 6,  $T_i^2 = T_i.T_i\to 0$ (sot) while it's not true. Is not it a counterexample for exercise 6? Thanks.

Comment: In the counterexample of Exercice 6, $(T_i)$ is not uniformly bounded.

Comment: @Etienne: because $T_i\to 0$ (sot), so it's uniformly bounded.

Comment: No. This is not a sequence.

Comment: @Etienne : For every $i$ and $\xi\in H$, we have $\|T_i\xi\|<\infty$, which shows that $\{T_i\}$ is uniformly bounded. Is not it correct?

Comment: No. Nothing tells you that $\sup_i \Vert T_i\xi\Vert<\infty$ for every $\xi$, because this is a net, not a sequence. So you cannot apply the uniform boundedness principle.

Comment: Based on      http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness , we can say $\{T_i\}$ is uniformly bounded. Where is my mistake?

Comment: It is exactly in what I said in my previous comment. For a general net (not a sequence) the fact that $T_i\xi\to 0$ does *not* imply that $\sup_i \Vert T_i\xi\Vert<\infty$; so UBP cannot be applied.

Comment: @Etienne:  So you mean that I can not say for $\epsilon>0$, there is a finite set $F\subset I$ such that $\|T_i\xi\|<\epsilon $ for $i\in I/F$.

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

The net $\{T_i\}$ in Exercise 8 does not meet the uniform boundedness hypothesis of Exercise 6, because $\|T_i\|=\sqrt{n_i}$, and the net $\{n_i\}$ is unbounded.